# HotKey for keyboard shortcut Linux/Windows (Launching the application)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, hotkeys

Hello everyone I have a task to make hotkeys to run the program.  And then two problems arose:

**1) In the windows implementation, I run the following code when creating a shortcut:**

```
  if( !file_path.empty() )
  {
     psl->SetIconLocation( lpsz_path_obj, 0 );
  }

  if( !target_path.empty() )
  {
     psl->SetPath( target_path.c_str() );
  }
  else
  {
     psl->SetPath( lpsz_path_obj );
  }
  psl->SetDescription( lpsz_desc );

  if( !command_args.empty() )
  {
     psl->SetArguments( lpsz_command );
  }

  psl->SetWorkingDirectory( working_dir.get() );

  WORD wHotKey = MAKEWORD( 0x55, HOTKEYF_CONTROL | HOTKEYF_ALT ); // Ctrl+Alt+U
  psl->SetHotkey( wHotKey );

  IPersistFilePtr ppf;
  hres = psl->QueryInterface( IID_IPersistFile, reinterpret_cast< LPVOID* >( &ppf ) );

  if( SUCCEEDED( hres ) )
  {
     hres = ppf->Save( lpsz_path_link, TRUE );
     if( !SUCCEEDED( hres ) )
     {
        exit_code = GetLastError();
        std::wcout << L"Save link failed: " << exit_code << std::endl;
     }
```

In all the manuals that I have read, in order to assign a shortcut to a hotkey, it is enough to do the following (which I do):

```
  WORD wHotKey = MAKEWORD( 0x55, HOTKEYF_CONTROL | HOTKEYF_ALT ); // Ctrl+Alt+U
  psl->SetHotkey( wHotKey );
```

The created shortcut launches my program, the assigned hotkey is displayed in the properties, but when you try to press the hotkey, nothing works. At the same time, if you assign a shortcut to a hotkey through the Windows interface, everything works.

**2) To implement hotkey in linux, I use gsettings. By executing commands in the console. I consistently perform the following:**

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name "mycombo"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding "['<Primary><Alt>d']"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command "chromium-browser"
```

So I create a slot, then specify the name of the bind, the key values for it, and the command to execute. This hotkey is displayed both in the keyboard settings and in dconf. But, as in the case of windows, it does not work. Although if you go to the keyboard settings, then open the installed keyboard shortcut and update, then it starts to work. What do I need to do to make it work immediately after executing the command in the terminal?

I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: I think Windows and Linux issues deserve separate questions

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Maybe, in essence, yes, but on the other hand, people who face a similar task will be able to find a solution for different platforms in one place.